# Error running Java application as SYSTEM using SCCM

Tags: java, deployment, operating-system, sccm

I'm attempting to run a Desktop installer using Microsoft's SCCM.  The installer was written using NSIS which predominantly executes Java calls.  This works great unless it's run as the `SYSTEM` profile using SCCM.  All Java calls look like this:

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Djna.nosys=true myapp.jar [options] ...
```

- ✅ When this application is run as a standard user, it works just fine.
- ⛔️ When this application is run as SYSTEM, it does not work.

Debugging this application we've found the following error is thrown:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 60928KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 1949696KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've tried using the recommendations from [this Harvard article](https://rce-docs.hmdc.harvard.edu/faq/why-do-i-get-java-error-could-not-reserve-enough-space-object-heap), but then I get a new error.

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=1 myapp.jar
#                                   ^--- NEW         ^--- NEW
```

The new error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
Java HotSpException in thread "main" ot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3192Kb max_used=3192Kb free=242567Kb
 bounds [0x00000295494c0000, 0x00000295497e0000, 0x00000295584c0000]
 total_blobs=1238 nmethods=897 adapters=254
 compilation: disabled (not enough contiguous free space left)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Why won't Java run properly as `SYSTEM` using SCCM?

Answer (score 0):

As a (non comprehensive) stop-gap solution, removing `-Xms512m` fixes the issue with SCCM.  Fortunately the installer doesn't require as much memory as requested.